# Remove garbage from Media/jw with command line

Tags: command-line, permissions

While running f3write erroneously at first I left some garbage files in my Media/jw directory - 1.h2w and 2.h2w. How do I get rid of them?

I can find them with the GUI but I don't have permission to remove anything there by deleting or dragging them to the trashcan.

With the command line I don't know how to get to that location in order to use sudo.

How do I cd above the Home directory using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can change directory `cd` to anywhere you have permission to *access* (The `x` in directory listings).

However, once you reach somewhere you can't access, you will need to either `sudo` specifically, e.g.

```
me@mycomputer$ sudo rm /path/to/files/to/delete/*.h2w
```

or you can **elevate** to a shell that is another user

```
me@mycomputer$ sudo su root
root@mycomputer$ cd /path/to/files/to/delete
root@mycomputer$ rm *.h2w
root@mycomputer$ exit
me@mycomputer$
```

If you don't specify which user you are elevating to, then the system will assume you mean root.  So you can just do

```
me@mycomputer$ sudo su
```

and the rest is the same.

**BE CAREFUL** - When you are root you can do **absolutely anything** and that includes shooting yourself in the foot.  Hence this joke from Randall of xkcd:

[image: Sudo Make me a sandwich kxcd joke.]

Comment: My problem is more simple. What is the <path to files> to Media/jw/ ? cd\ doesn't work. cd.. doesn't work. I'm missing something really basic - how do I describe the path above Home?

Comment: Yes, we use a forward-slash `/` for path separators, and you need a space between `cd` and `/` or `cd` and `..`.  I know this can be confusing if you've come from DOS!  And case is important in Ubuntu so it's not `Media/jw` it's `/media/jw`.

Comment: And `/path/to/files` in this case would be `/media/<username>/<deviceID>` where <username> is your username from `whoami` and <deviceID> is the name of the device, which could be a UUID or a disk label.  Just type `ls /media/jw/` and it will be listed.